# Queryin One-to-Many same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a below table with sample data as below:

```
prod    seq catid
-------------------
prod1   0   10
prod1   1   20
prod1   2   30
prod1   3   40
prod2   0   10
prod3   0   10
prod3   1   20
prod3   2   30
prod4   0   10
```

I need to query above table based on catid column.
Ex: If i query with catid - 10 then i need to get all products(here prod2, prod3, prod4) which has only catid as 10 all the other should be excluded.
Same way if i query with catid = 10 20 30 then i need to get output as prod3, if i query with catid as 10 20 30 40 then my output should be prod1.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE catid = ALL (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I tried using ALL in my query but i am not able to get desired output, please help.

Comment: Can you add the expected result too?

Comment: When i query with catid = 1,2,3,4,5 i need to get prod1 and if i query with catid = 1,2,3,4 i need to get prod2

Answer (score 1):

You can get the expected `prod` value using the query:

```
SELECT prod
FROM mytable
GROUP BY prod
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catId) = 5 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN catId NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above query returns products having `5` *distinct* `catId` values. None of these values doesn't belong to `(1,2,3,4,5)` set of values.

Comment: But this would rule out a `prod` group if it had anything _other_ than 1-5, which maybe isn't what the OP wants.  I see no "nice" way of doing this query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I *think* the OP wants products having *all* values and nothing but these values.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT prod
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY prod
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN catid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN catid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN catid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN catid = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN catid = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that is more generalised - it relies on you passing in a string to the query consisting of a comma separated list (no spaces) into the query:

```
WITH   your_table AS (SELECT 'prod1' prod, 0 seq, 10 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod1' prod, 0 seq, 20 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod1' prod, 0 seq, 30 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod1' prod, 0 seq, 40 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod2' prod, 0 seq, 10 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod3' prod, 0 seq, 10 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod3' prod, 0 seq, 20 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod3' prod, 0 seq, 30 catid FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'prod4' prod, 0 seq, 10 catid FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table with sample data in it
-- see sql below:
SELECT   yt.prod
FROM     your_table yt
GROUP BY yt.prod
HAVING   min(CASE WHEN ','||:p_string_to_compare||',' LIKE '%,'||yt.catid||',%' THEN 'Y'
                  ELSE 'N'
             END) = 'Y'
AND      count(*) = regexp_count(:p_string_to_compare, ',') + 1;
```

With :p_string = '10,40,30,20':

```
PROD
-----
prod1
```

With :p_string = '10,20,30':

```
PROD
-----
prod3
```

With :p_string = '10, 20':

```
no rows returned
```

With :p_string = '10':

```
PROD
-----
prod4
prod2
```